# Add vertical elements to horizontal push list from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Maybe a trick question. I am trying to make an golf scorecard by pulling data through ajax/json.

Here is how i get the scorecard.

php:

```
$scorecard = array();
$players = array();
$data = array();

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ga_turndata WHERE fk_turnid = 1 ORDER BY hole_no ASC LIMIT 18");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $scorecard[] = array('hole' => $row['hole_no'], 'par' => $row['par'], 'hcp' => $row['hcp']);
}

$players[] = array('user' => 'Jane Doe', 'id' => '89', 'useraStrokes' => '5');
$players[] = array('user' => 'Jemaine Dice', 'id' => '245', 'useraStrokes' => '17');
$players[] = array('user' => 'Jimmie Gallon', 'id' => '16', 'useraStrokes' => '13');

$data = array('scorecard' => $scorecard, 'players' => $players);
```

With help from stackoverflow users I got it to work with sending 2 different arrays through json.

I get the data like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://mypage.com/json/scorecard.php', function(data) {

        var array = [];
        var c = 0;

        $.each(data.players, function(i, player){
            eval("player" + i + " = player.user");
            c++;
        });

        $.each(data.scorecard, function (i, scorecard) {

            array.push($("#theholes").append("<li><div class='holeinfo'>"+scorecard.hole+"</div><div id='players'>Here i want to dynamicly add players from the first $.each</div></li>"));

        });
});
```

Getting the 18 holes is no problem, but cant figure how I do append the players dynamicly into the $each loop?

Hope this makes sense!?! Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Why $.each ? Just use a good old for loop with an index that you can use in both arrays...

Comment: Any suggestion how to do this?